# combining n elements of iterable1 with m elements of iterable2

Tags: python, python-itertools

how do i combine n items from iterable1 with m items from iterable2?

i.e.

```
iterable1 = [0,1,2,3,4]
iterable2 = ['a','b','c']
BlackBox(itertools.combination(iterable1, 2),itertools.combination(iterable2, 1)) yields
(0,1,'a'), (0,1,'b'), (0,1,'c'), (0,2,'a'), (0,3,'a'), etc. Order doesn't matter
```

I'm receiving a list of elements, which may contain a wildcard which I then need to replace with all of the wildcard's possible values. I check for the number of wildcards and need to add a combination of that many elements into my de-wildcarded list. In other words, iterable2 is all the possible values of the wildcard, m is the number of wildcards, iterable1 is the original list with all wildcards removed, and n is the number of desired items less m.

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: how do i combine n items from iterable1 with m items from iterable2?

Comment: I've tried itertools.product but it doesn't combine the elements correctly because I end up with nested tuples.

Comment: You could use product and then [flatten the result](http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/Cartesian-Product-of-two-lists-itertools-td1524206.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> iterable1 = [0,1,2,3,4]
>>> iterable2 = ['a','b','c']
>>> import itertools as it
>>> list(x+y for x,y in it.product(it.combinations(iterable1, 2), it.combinations(iterable2, 1)))
[(0, 1, 'a'), (0, 1, 'b'), (0, 1, 'c'), (0, 2, 'a'), (0, 2, 'b'), (0, 2, 'c'), (0, 3, 'a'), (0, 3, 'b'), (0, 3, 'c'), (0, 4, 'a'), (0, 4, 'b'), (0, 4, 'c'), (1, 2, 'a'), (1, 2, 'b'), (1, 2, 'c'), (1, 3, 'a'), (1, 3, 'b'), (1, 3, 'c'), (1, 4, 'a'), (1, 4, 'b'), (1, 4, 'c'), (2, 3, 'a'), (2, 3, 'b'), (2, 3, 'c'), (2, 4, 'a'), (2, 4, 'b'), (2, 4, 'c'), (3, 4, 'a'), (3, 4, 'b'), (3, 4, 'c')]
```